# Index/Match Formula for Values That don't match multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to have a INDEX MATCH Function that will look at the date in column B and will retrieve a value from the column G (the rotation list) that does not match someone who is out of Office for that particular Date in column B.

I have created a Index Match Array function but it is not taking into account everyone that is out of office and will just grab a value from a list that does not match the initial look up value.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qzyu3.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iy2bw.png)

**This Formula is used on the calculation tab I just need it to account for people that are out of office (I left this out of the initial question to make it less complex): =IFNA(IF(OR(B4=$I4,B4=$O4,B4=$U4,B4=$AG4,B4=$AM4,B4=$AS4,B4=$BU$1),INDEX('Input Data (For Schedule Prep)'!$A$2:$A$7,MATCH(1,(C3<>'Input Data (For Schedule Prep)'!$D$2:$D$20)*(C5<>'Input Data (For Schedule Prep)'!$D$2:$D$20)*(I4<>'Input Data (For Schedule Prep)'!$A$2:$A$7)*(O4<>'Input Data (For Schedule Prep)'!$A$2:$A$7)*(U4<>'Input Data (For Schedule Prep)'!$A$2:$A$7)*(AG4<>'Input Data (For Schedule Prep)'!$A$2:$A$7)*(AM4<>'Input Data (For Schedule Prep)'!$A$2:$A$7)*(AS4<>'Input Data (For Schedule Prep)'!$A$2:$A$7)*(B4<>'Input Data (For Schedule Prep)'!$A$2:$A$7)*($BU$1<>'Input Data (For Schedule Prep)'!$B$2:$B$20),0)),B4),B4)**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF9yy.png)

Comment: Do you want a random value? Or is there some logic to which name should be picked (as long as that person is out of office?

Comment: I'd like the value to be retrieved from the rotation list in Column G, this individual would be in the office (All of the green values). The value that is retrieved cannot match any individual that is out of office in column J base on the date. The retrieved value would populate in Column D.

Comment: Yes. I get that. But there needs to be *some* logic... why choose `Tammy` instead of `Frank` or `Tom` for the first instance? Seems like you want a random person chosen, as long as they are in the office.

Comment: Ya a random value at this point will work, I'm just unaware how to get that. Once I have that part I'll tweak the criteria because there are a bunch of other factors I have to take into account. It is one piece to a automatic calendar I'm creating.

Comment: I came up with another formula, that I think is pretty close but is still not working. Any suggestions? (See attached photo)